# php loop through complex posts

Tags: php, associative-array

I am new to web programming and I have such a complex posts all over my work this was the result for a `var_dump($_POST)` , I am using `gettype()` function to determine that if the value in the `$arr` array is another array or not , I am not convenient of such behave of code of mine , neither the problems that I always met when going to loop for insertion

the question is if there is smarter technique to loop within like this complex posts , secondly how to catch the name,phone in the 2d array that called `assistant` (called `assistant['name']`,`assistant[phone]`)

```
<?php

    $arr = array(
                 "name"=> "mmmkkkk", 
                 "phones"=> array(
                                  "01553338897" , 
                                  "09090909098"
                                 ), 
                 "address"=> "107 ostras., Germany", 
                 "assistant"=> array(
                                      "name" => array(
                                                      "kmkkm",
                                                      "komar"
                                                     ), 
                                      "phone"=> array(
                                                      "01043338897" , 
                                                      "09099090090"
                                                     )
                                   )
                );

    foreach($arr as $key => $p_value)
    {
            if(gettype($p_value)=="array")
            {
                echo $key.":"."</br>";

                foreach($p_value as $newp_value => $val )
                {
                    if(gettype($val)=="array")
                    {
                        foreach($val as $vkey)
                        {
                            echo $vkey."</br>"; 
                        }
                    }
                    else{echo $val."</br>";}
                }       

            }else{echo $key.":".$p_value."</br>";}
    }   

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Recursive` function like this.

```
<?php
    $arr = array(
                 "name"=> "mmmkkkk", 
                 "phones"=> array(
                                  "01553338897" , 
                                  "09090909098"
                                 ), 
                 "address"=> "107 ostras., Germany", 
                 "assistant"=> array(
                                      "name" => array(
                                                      "kmkkm",
                                                      "komar"
                                                     ), 
                                      "phone"=> array(
                                                      "01043338897" , 
                                                      "09099090090"
                                                     )
                                   )
                );

    function rec($arr) {

        foreach($arr as $key => $p_value)
        {
            if (is_array($p_value)) {
                rec($p_value);
            } else {
                echo $key.":".$p_value."\n";
            }
        }

    }

    rec($arr);

?>
```

Comment: abc($p_value);  should be rec($p_value);

Comment: Opps!! Thank you. @RavinderReddy

Comment: thanks for the powerful of knowing ,... if there is any good way to handle the assistant array ? via assistant['name']['phone']
rather than loop on each column separatly

Comment: So you want this format: `assistant:<br> name:phone`. Right ? Yes. It's possible. Before that I need to know something. Is the array format of assistant array changeable or always follows current format ?

Comment: <tr class="assphone">
   <td><b>Assistant:</b></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="assistant[name][]" class="form-control" placeholder="Assistant Name"/></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="assistant[phone][]" class="form-control" placeholder="Assistant Phone"/></td>
   <td><span class="btn btn-success spanbutton addassphone"> + </span></td>
  </tr>

that <tr> is regenerated if i want to add more than assistant so multiple <tr>s for multiple assistants ...

Answer (score 0):

Think recursive

```
function walkThrough($array, $tabulation = 0) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        printf ('%s%s:', str_repeat(4*$tabulation, '&nbsp;'));

        if (is_array($value))   walkThrough ( $value, ($tabulation+1) );
        else                   printf('%s<br />', $value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Recursive function

```
function recursivefunc($arr,$key =''){
if(is_array($arr)){
    foreach($arr as $k => $v){
        if (is_array($v) && !empty($v)) {
            recursivefunc($v,$k);
        } else {
            $keys = ($key=='') ? $k : $key;
            echo $keys.":".$v.'</br>';
        }
    }
}
}
recursivefunc($arr);
```

Out put :

```
name:mmmkkkk
phones:01553338897
phones:09090909098
address:107 ostras., Germany
name:kmkkm
name:komar
phone:01043338897
phone:09099090090
```